# ADB is not working and failed to initialize the monitor thread error occurred in the ddms in android

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-service, android-2.2-froyo

My android sdk is not working properly. There is a problem in the ADB and DDMS.

I tried  `adb kill-server`, it works fine. Then 
I wrote `adb start-server` but it does not work and give something in output which is as follows:

```
daemon is not running starting it now on port 5037.ADB sever didn't ACK
```

I have no clue about how to make changes.

Also one more thing which occurred in ddms is

> [2012-02-29 18:43:54 - ddms] Failed to initialize Monitor Thread:
>   Unable to establish loopback connection
>   [2012-02-29 18:43:55 - adb]
>   ADB server didn't ACK

My firewall is also off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

first kill process of adb from task maanger. shutdown your eclipse.. wait 3 sec if you see any eclipse process in task manager, do kill it.

go to cmd
type `adb kill-server` then type `adb devices` (don't call adb start-server)

start your eclipse and you are good to go.

Comment: It sometimes happens if you have two simultaneous eclipse instances open and you try to debug on one instance.

Comment: now the ADB is working but the new issue is is there when i run my app on emulater that is[2012-03-01 16:34:08 - ktrivia] Android Launch!
 adb is running normally.
Performing com.ktrivia.in.KtriviaActivity activity launch
Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'Deepu' is not available. Launching new emulator.
[2012-03-01 16:34:08 - ktrivia] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Deepu'
[2012-03-01 16:34:10 - Emulator] emulator: warning: opening audio input failed
 
[2012-03-01 16:34:13 - Emulator] emulator: WARNING: Unable to create sensors port: Unknown error

Comment: thanks it works and finally my prob is solved

Comment: then I deserve +1 ;-) at-least :D

Comment: Hi Algo i faced the same prob. again and the steps which help me earlier didn't work for me this time. Please suggest me something useful

Comment: go to pref->ddms-> increase connection timeout It might help you :)